# How to divide a String into identical repeating parts

Tags: java, string

Given a String, I want to divide it up into substrings that are all identical. For example:

- `"abcabcabcabc"` -> `["abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"]`
- `"aaaaaa"` -> `["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"]`
- `"abc"` -> `["abc"]`

My problem is figuring out the logic of finding where to break the characters. My approach initial attempt is:

```
public static void FindPattern(String s) {  

    int no_of_characters = 256;
    int[] count = new int[no_of_characters];
    Arrays.fill(count, 0);

    for (int i= 0; i < s.length();i++){
         count[s.charAt(i)]++;
    }       
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcabcabd";
    FindPattern(s);
}
```

but I have no idea of where to go from there.

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what the rules are for dividing the input and what's wrong with what your code is doing vs what it should be doing

Comment: Now please check if it makes enough meaning

Comment: What if the input is `"aaaaaa"`: Is the result `a a a a a a`, `aa aa aa` or `aaa aaa`? Also, you haven't yet said what result your code produces.

Comment: Yes you are right if input is "aaaaa" output will be a a a a a.   One more if input is "abccbaabccba" output will be abccba  - abccba

Comment: And what does your code produce for various inputs (you have been asked 3 times now for this but still not rpovided it)

Comment: I am unable to get to the final answer and need help for the logic path. I am not able to think where should I approach and in which direction. Code is not producing anything at the moment

Comment: A simple approach: split the string in half. See if the halves match. If not, subtract one char from the string and repeat.

Comment: Thanks seems legit Ill try and then post my answer thanks buddy

Comment: @Adit please edit your question to include the output your current code produces

Comment: @AdityaVerma If you really want to learn things then give a considerable time in thinking and figuring out stuff. To start with, forget the coding part and just ask yourself that how did your brain concluded that what will be the substrings (abc) after you saw a String(abcabcabcabc).

Comment: Ayushi Jain, You are right but sometimes I am unable to write things and sometimes I can write pretty hard codes as well. I don't understand why such things happen

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find the smallest substring that when repeated is the same as the whole string:

```
String part = str.replaceAll("^(.+?)\\1*$", "$1");
```

Breaking down the regex:

- `^` means "start of input"
- `(.*?)` means "capture (as group 1) the smallest amount of input that will result in a match"
- `\1` is a *back reference* to group 1, meaning "another copy of what was captured in group 1"
- `*` zero or more of the the back reference
- `$1` the replacement is what was captured in group 1

Because zero further copies are allowed to complete the match, when there is no repeating group, the whole string is returned, which is correct behaviour.

Once you have this string, you don't actually need to "divide" the string up, you just need `n` copies of it. However as a convenience you can split the sting equal parts by splitting on the length of the result of the above:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\G.{" + str.replaceAll("^(.*?)\\1*$", "$1").length() + "})");
```

More simply, the split regex is `(?<=\G.{n})`, which means "there are n characters between the end of the previous match and the current position".

Comment: Finally I have a Solution for this !